# My Apps admin not working

Tags: foursquare

Today and yesterday while logged into developer.foursquare.com when I click on My Apps in the top nav bar (which is linked to https://foursquare.com/oauth/) then I get the 404 display.

Is this a problem with the site, or just my account? The other nav links (Overview, Endpoints, etc) are fine.

Comment: Try without the final '/' and it should be correct.. let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct URL you should call is:

> https://foursquare.com/oauth

Comment: The link will be fixed on the site tomorrow